# Table Partitioning in MySql and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, indexing, partitioning, sharding

In my project I have a table with around 20 columns. We have partitioned table on column 'status'. For the sake of simplicity let's say there are two possible values of status "ERROR" and "SUCCESS". Hence we have two partitions say p1 and p2 for the table. What we want is to have different indexes on each of the partitions since select queries will use different columns in where clause depending upon status. For example, partition p1 needs to have index on column1 and column2 whereas partition p2 needs to have index on column 4 and column 5. However I have learnt that it is not possible to apply index at partition level in MySql 5.5.

So now other option could be to have different tables for each status. I am using Hibernate at application layer. Is it possible to configure Hibernate such that I have one Entity class for both the tables. So that when status changes from "ERROR" to "SUCCESS", record is automatically moved from Error table to Success table behind the scene. As a developer I only need to work upon Entity object and need not worry from which table it is getting picked up from. Hibernate should do the handling of moving data from one table to another. This way I will be able to maintain different indexes on different tables. This is more like manual partition than db partitioning.

I have heard of Hibernate Shard project. But I think it is useful when you have different database for same table. Here I have single database with two tables for same entity.

Comment: you could make it to classes inheriting a base class, one for each value of type. But the moving of data has to be implemented by yourself, hibernate won't do this automaticly

Comment: That is what exactly I am doing currently. However I wished if there was a way to tell Hibernate to do so automatically.